# Installing rtl88x2bu driver with dkms fails

Tags: drivers, dkms

I've downloaded the driver from official website, however I'm having trouble making it work with dkms.

I cd into driver's directory, then:

```
sudo dkms add .
```

Which adds it correctly.

However, when I try to build it or install it, it fails:

```
$ sudo dkms install rtl88x2bu/5.8.7

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-52-generic KVER=5.4.0-52-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.8.7 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7/build/make.log for more information.
```

Then I check what went wrong:

```
$ cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for rtl88x2bu-5.8.7 for kernel 5.4.0-52-generic (x86_64)
уто, 27. окт 2020.  12:49:04 CET
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I do not understand what's going on.

This is my `dkms.conf`:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl88x2bu"
PACKAGE_VERSION="5.8.7"
MAKE[0]="make KVER=$kernelver src=$source_tree/rtl88x2bu-$PACKAGE_VERSION"
CLEAN="make clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="88x2bu"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/net"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

I have tried to append `all`, `modules`, and whatnot to `MAKE[0]`, however nothing worked out.

I do not want to use the driver that can be found on GitHub, as this one is newer and comes from trusted source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to put `make` around single quotes, and that solved it.

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl88x2bu"
PACKAGE_VERSION="5.8.7"
MAKE[0]="'make' KVER=$kernelver src=$source_tree/rtl88x2bu-$PACKAGE_VERSION"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="88x2bu"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/net"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

Silly.